# ¿Cómo almaceno el select en esa variable llamada Sald y luego hacer un insert con esa variable? SQL-SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

```
CREATE PROC Ps_Saldos

@Cod_Pago int
as
begin
declare @Sald bigint
declare 
SELECT @Sald= (SELECT T1.Valor - (SELECT SUM (T2.Valor) 
FROM Reversion T2
Where T1.Cod_Pago = T2.Cod_Pago ) FROM Pago T1)
insert into Saldos(Cod_Pago,Saldo)values(@Cod_Pago,@Sald) 
end
go
```

Me tira este error :

> La subconsulta ha devuelto más de un valor, lo que no es correcto
>   cuando va a continuación de =, !=, <, <=, >, >= o cuando se utiliza
>   como expresión.

Comment: Debes usar el equivalente en SQL SERVER a `LIMIT 1` de MySQL creo recordar, porque las subconsultas solo pueden devolver un valor y en variables igual, solo se puede almacenar un valor y la consulta debe de estar arrojando más de uno.

Comment: Como el mensaje dice, la sub-consulta `SELECT T1.Valor ...` devuelve mas de un resultado, por lo que no está claro cual de esos resultados se deba asignar a `@Sald`.  Para recomendarte una solución adecuada, primero debes explicar bien lo que pretendes lograr, incluyendo ejemplos concretos con datos.

Comment: Aunque esto en efecto eliminaría el mensaje de error, no necesariamente daría el resultado deseado.  De hecho, lo mas probable es que el resultado sería incorrecto. Primero hay que entender lo que OP pretende lograr con su consulta.

Answer (score 0):

El Select que pusiste me parece muy raro.. en este caso simplemente bastaría con un join y creo que también te falto filtrar el select con un where con el parámetro que recibís, que seria @cod_Pago.
**Pongo comentado lo que cambie con --**

Yo lo haria asi:

```
CREATE PROC Ps_Saldos
@Cod_Pago int
as
begin
declare @Sald bigint
--declare 
--SELECT @Sald = (SELECT T1.Valor - (SELECT SUM(T2.Valor) 
--                FROM Reversion T2
--                Where T1.Cod_Pago = T2.Cod_Pago ) 
--                FROM Pago T1)

Select @sald = (SELECT T1.Valor - T2.Valor
   FROM Pago T1
   inner join (SELECT SUM(T2.Valor) valor
               FROM Reversion T2
               group by Cod_pago) T2) T2 on T1.Cod_Pago = T2.Cod_Pago 
where T1.Cod_pago = @Cod_Pago

insert into Saldos(Cod_Pago,Saldo)values(@Cod_Pago,@Sald) 
end
go
```

Comment: OP comentó: *Me dice sintaxis incorrecta  cerca del 'on' porque sera ? me falta algo?*

Comment: faltaba el alias al subselect.. lo he editado ahora